# Accesing EXT3 partition form WIN XP

Tags: linux, windows, ext3, ext2

I have WIN XP partition on my PC. It is used from time to time, but I need access to one particular EXT3 formatted Linux filesystem in read/write mode.
Sourceforge offers Ext2Fsd. Nice, but it works in read/write mode only with EXT2 filesystem type. Operating on EXT3 formated cause from time to time damage of EXT3 filesystem during access it to write mode. fsck resolve the problem, but I want to live without problems.

So my questions are:
- is it possible to replace Ext2Fsd by any WIN XP driver with read/write full support for EXT3
- is it possible to migrate desired filesystem to EXT2 from EX3. I mean about some simple solution, not backing-up, formating and restoring. And of course changing UUID in fstab.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think than anything better than Ext2Fsd exists.

About your second question, you can try this (found on [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=56621)):

1. First, make sure the partition you are about to convert isn't mounted.
2. Turn off the journalizing flag on the partition : `sudo tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/hdxx`
3. `sudo e2fsck /dev/hdxx` (since the filesystem no longer has a journal the check assumes the filesystem is ext2 and cleans it up)
4. Edit `/etc/fstab`  and change the partitions' filesystem from ext3 to ext2.